# Slow character display while typing in MS Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-office

I have an MS Word document with many, many headings. I am now experiencing lag especially in typing. I just would like to know if this is a limitation of MS Word, and if I cannot do anything about it. When I open a new document, I can type smoothly.

I already tried opening in safe mode but it's still the same. I hope there's a solution because I still have a loooooong way to go before I could finish this document.

Additional info:

- I am also tracking the changes because this is a business documentation. I tried turning it off but the performance is still the same.
- I turned off the animation but the performance is still the same.
- I opened the file in Office 2007 and it runs faster... Hmmm...

Comment: Try disabling plugins. Can you include a screenshot of the Word process in task manager?

Answer (score 0):

The delay is likely a result of spelling and grammar checking. Try turning those off and see if speed isn't improved.

```
File -> Options -> uncheck "Check spelling as you type"
```

also

```
File -> Options -> Proofing -> uncheck "Mark grammar errors as you type"
```

Comment: I already turned it off like you said, but the performance is still the same. Maybe this is because I track the changes, but I cannot turn it off because I need it.

Comment: You could try breaking your document into several smaller documents.

Comment: I actually did. I already cut it in half, and it's only 184 pages.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of OneDrive.

Next to the clock (right bottom of the screen) you would see OneDrive's cloud sign. Right click to it and go to settings. In Office tab, uncheck "Use Office to sync Office files"

That sorted out similar problem I had.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)